# android recyclerView's view item's onConfigurationChanged is not called

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-orientation, onconfigurationchanged

Has

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

and there are some custom view (root from RelativeLayout), which has

```
    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        // do something to react
    }
```

the same custom view is used in either scrollView or recyclerView.

in same activity/fragment when place the custom view in the scrollerView its `onConfigurationChanged` is called when rotate, but place it in the recyclerView the `onConfigurationChanged` is not called.

The code has no difference except one use scrollView, one use recyclerView.
Is it a known behavior?  Or how to make the view item's `onConfigurationChanged` to be called when place it in the recyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is different how the custom view is placed in the parent container.
When add to recyclerview view holder, it is wrapped in a FrameLayout first, so one more layer view which seems prevents the custom view's onConfigurationChange getting called (since the custome view is not the direct view in the viewholder).